# ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

Tags: windows, tensorflow

My computer has i7 processor and Windows 10, 64 bit. I installed Python 3.5.2.
When I run python from console, it shows "Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32". I added python to path. I didn't install Anaconda. Shouldn't python be 64 bit on a 64 bit OS?

I also installed CUDA on C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\cuda\ and I added its bin folder to path. I installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable for x64.

The computer does not have NVIDIA graphics card. Do I still need to install CUDA_8.0.61? I installed it anyway and I still have the error listed in the title.

Anything else should I check?

Comment: I solved it by uninstalling both python for 32 bit and 64 bit and anaconda from Control Panel. Next, I reinstalled Python for 64 bit, v3.5.2 and I used pip3 to install tensorflow. I also found that in the environment path I had added by mistake the path for the 32 bit python and I corrected the path.

Answer (score 0):

When I launch python from console, it should indicate it is version 3.5.2 and that it runs on 64 bit (MSC v1.900 64 bit (AMD64)). Even for i7 processors, we can run the AMD version. If the default version of python is not right, edit the environment path. It should indicate C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35.
For computers without NVIDIA graphics card, it is not necessary to install CUDA software.